# Check if my twilio number is busy

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I have **one twilio number XXXXXXXXXX** , now using which I want my users to experience the calling functionalities as I can't afford individual number for each user.

Thus I need to know how to retrieve status of my own number? Basically if the number is being used for another call at the moment.

One thought is making a call to the number itself, but that would give me status busy in the first place.

Would request help in the following. TIA

Comment: Do you want to use the one single number only for outbound or inbound calls or both at the same time?

Comment: It's for outbound and inbound calls most likely be restricted

Comment: What happens if you try an outbound call while another outbound call from this number is in progress? If it throws an error, handle it accordingly. I must admit I'm having hard time finding responses and possible error responses from Twilio API docs. The second idea is to track number usage yourself by using the ``StatusCallback`` optional parameter when starting a call (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional). Provide a webhook to track call progress and you can always check progress from your own storage when starting a new one.

Answer (score 6):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio numbers themselves will never be busy. A Twilio number can route new calls even while other calls are ongoing. The only thing that could be busy is a non-Twilio number that you are trying to forward a call to.